# Обрезка отсканенных изображений на C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно сделать программу на С#, которая должна поворачивать и обрезать отсканенные изображения. С поворотом я разобрался, а вот с обрезкой проблема, так как из-за качества сканера на областях, которые необходимо обрезать, могут быть области отличные по цвету с общим фоном (например, мелкие частицы чего-то). Поэтому обрезать только черный или белый цвет нельзя. Я пытался использовать детекторы углов, но они находят углы на тех областях, которые мне нужно обрезать из-за мусора.

Знаю, что можно пойти "тупым" путем: взять по 2 линии с каждой стороны скана, каждый пиксель в этих линиях проверять. Но это слишком долго, ибо таких сканов имеется несколько миллионов и необходимо автоматизировать процесс.

Есть какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: Всем спасибо, я сам уже разобрался.

Comment: А как решил проблему? Я пытался найти решение, но не смог :(

Comment: Как было сказано, я использую AForge.NET. В самом начале я делаю уменшенную копию скана, потом на этой копии я использую OtsuThreshold, потом GaussianBlur/GaussianSharpen для устранения шумов и мелкого мусора. Потом применяю Threshold со значением из OtsuThreshold. И наконец SusanCornersDetector для определения углов, границ. Потом координаты привожу к оригинальному размеру. Почитай документацию к данным фильтрам. Не знаю правильный метод или нет, но работает быстро и пока без ошибок! :)

Answer (score 1):

Для обработки изображений существует хорошая библиотека под .NET. Это [AForge.NET](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/). Есть ненулевой шанс, что она содержит готовое или близкое к готовому решение.

Кроме того, открыт код [системы распознавания документов](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/) от Google (не C#). Возможно, там найдется что-то подходящее.

Comment: Извини, что не указал, но я ей и пользуюсь! :). Там именно этого нет.